# inline-block scrollbars when browser resized

Tags: html, css

Here is my css:

```css
.contain
{
  min-width: 300px;
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}
.inl1{
  /* margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px; */
  min-width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class=contain>
  <div class=inl1></div>
</div>

<div class=contain>
  <div class=inl1></div>
</div>
```

Clearly the two divs display inline, which is what I want.

However, when the browser is resized smaller  the divs are displayed one above the other (desired behaviour), but once I make the browser window smaller than min-width, I need to have horizontal scrollbars displayed. This is not happening.

Any help as to why?

Edited: I tried the suggestions here, but they all seem to break the desired behaviour of the divs stacking on top of each other when the browser is sized smaller.

The effect I am after:

display the divs inline (with no scrollbars) in a browser that is wide enough; but in a "narrow" browser (ie mobile) display the divs one on top of another and THEN add horizontal scrolling ONCE the min-width can no longer be displayed for each div.

I think that's a little clearer...

Comment: A wild guess: Give the `<body>` or any other container a defined width. I am not too sure, though.

Comment: The issue is that you wrapping boxes have ` min-width: 300px;`, which means they won't change size. I think you are looking for ` width: 50%; max-width: 300px;`, which will size those boxes independently from its content.

Comment: Question edited for clarity about exactly what it is I want to achieve.

Comment: Either way, the solution is still the same, your need a box that actually _can_ scale to a size smaller than your inner box. Check my answer with its media query to stack them back like they should...

Answer (score 0):

Your outside boxes have the same minimum width as your inside ones, so both will be *at least* 300px wide, so no scrollbars appear. Because of the defined pixelwidth of your outer elements, your they will not stack next to each other if you do not have 600 pixels to play with or more. If you give your outer boxes a width that can scale (by using `%` or `vw`) with the page width, your result magically appears:

```css
.contain {
  width: 45%;
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}
.inl1{
  /* margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px; */
  min-width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
@media all and (max-width:600px){
  .contain {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=contain>
  <div class=inl1></div>
</div>

<div class=contain>
  <div class=inl1></div>
</div>
```

(I use `45%` because I did not want to bother with floating these nicely next to each other, but you could with some more CSS). You can still add a `max-width` of 300 pixels to your containers to make sure they don't grow *beyond* 300px, but still shrink otherwise.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I don't want the divs to display inline at all in a "too small" (ie not wide enough) browser. I am basically trying to have two different layouts: inline for "wide enough" browsers and on top of each other, with horiz scrolls when the div content can no longer fit in the browser's width.

Comment: @user5916352 You might need to go the way of a media query for this to make it as good as possible. I'll add a line to my answer code. But in essence, the trick is the same and the reason that its not scrolling is the same - your inner box is exactly the width of your outer box, so it will not generate scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have a wrapper for the divs and set it with

```
.wrapper{
   min-width: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1hshzxah/3/

Comment: The issue is not a wrapper, it's that the width are defined in pixels and as min-widths... Wrappers are just more code, your `body` is a wrapper as well, so no need to complexify...

Comment: Thank you, but it breaks the "stack on top of each other" behaviour in a narrow browser. I edited the question.